# Understanding digital signature

Tags: ssl, encryption, digital-signature, tls1.2

As per my understanding digital signature take advantage of asymmetric encryption.
Owner signs content by encrypting [private key] and all other users decrypt using public key and then compare to plain text. Is that right?

Also, in one of the steps in SSL/TLS handshake protocol user sends to server a message wich holds: Signature_user(PreMasterKey, ...).
As per my understanding a third party can just decrypt using the public key and get the PreMasterKey which supposed to be secret.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a crypto question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding of a digital signature is close to correct. Because asymmetric encryption is limited in how much data it can actually encrypt and decrypt (for instance, RSA-4096 can encrypt at most 446B), the digital signature is usually `Encrypt(Hash(message), privateKey)` where `Hash()` is a cryptographic hash function like `SHA-256`. This value can be decrypted by anyone using the signer's public key, and the same hash algorithm applied locally to the suspect message in order to verify the signature. You can demonstrate this for yourself, for example when using `gpg`:

```
hw12203:/Users/alopresto/Workspace/scratch (master) alopresto
 14s @ 15:49:46 $ echo "This is a test" > sign.txt
hw12203:/Users/alopresto/Workspace/scratch (master) alopresto
 11s @ 15:52:30 $ gpg --sign sign.txt
hw12203:/Users/alopresto/Workspace/scratch (master) alopresto
 60s @ 15:53:22 $ xxd sign.txt.gpg
0000000: a301 014d 02b2 fd90 0d03 000a 013c 6ef6  ...M.........<n.
0000010: 5b2f 7def 6901 ac1d 6208 7369 676e 2e74  [/}.i...b.sign.t
0000020: 7874 5882 a322 5468 6973 2069 7320 6120  xtX.."This is a
0000030: 7465 7374 0a89 021c 0400 010a 0006 0502  test............
...
0000250: 1999 83c9                                ....
hw12203:/Users/alopresto/Workspace/scratch (master) alopresto
 100s @ 15:54:11 $ gpg --verify -vvv sign.txt.gpg
gpg: using character set `utf-8'
:compressed packet: algo=1
:onepass_sig packet: keyid 3C6EF65B2F7DEF69
    version 3, sigclass 0x00, digest 10, pubkey 1, last=1
:literal data packet:
    mode b (62), created 1484956450, name="sign.txt",
    raw data: 15 bytes
gpg: original file name='sign.txt'
:signature packet: algo 1, keyid 3C6EF65B2F7DEF69
    version 4, created 1484956450, md5len 0, sigclass 0x00
    digest algo 10, begin of digest 98 8e
    hashed subpkt 2 len 4 (sig created 2017-01-20)
    subpkt 16 len 8 (issuer key ID 3C6EF65B2F7DEF69)
    data: [4092 bits]
gpg: Signature made Fri Jan 20 15:54:10 2017 PST using RSA key ID 2F7DEF69
gpg: using PGP trust model
gpg: key 00D026C4: accepted as trusted key
gpg: key 51BF2B79: accepted as trusted key
gpg: key 2F7DEF69: accepted as trusted key
gpg: Good signature from "Andy LoPresto <alopresto@apache.org>" [ultimate]
gpg:                 aka "Andy LoPresto <alopresto.apache@gmail.com>" [ultimate]
gpg: binary signature, digest algorithm SHA512
hw12203:/Users/alopresto/Workspace/scratch (master) alopresto
 10s @ 15:54:22 $
```

Note that the signing operation *does not encrypt* the message (you can see the plaintext of the message in the signature file), and that the signature uses the underlying hash function `SHA-512` (visible if you verify with `-vvv`).

As for your second question, the pre-master secret is never shared over an open channel. It is derived on both sides of the channel independently using the shared keying material (i.e. nonce, etc.). This can be done with (ephemeral) [Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) (aka "paint mixing") or another process. If raw RSA is used for the key exchange, the client sends a nonce *encrypted* with the server's public key to provide the pre-master secret.

To fully understand the TLS handshake process, read [this explanation by Thomas Pornin](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/20847/16485) (the best I've ever seen). Once you've read that, the [IETF RFC 5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) (TLS 1.2) will make much more sense and you can get into the weeds if you want.